# Display sql tables in separate html table columns

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm trying to display data from different mysql tables in an html table. The problem I have is that it currently displays both in the same column. I'd like to have two separate columns in the table one for each of the sql data.

This is my code:

```
global $wpdb;
$centr = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT meta_value FROM `wp__frm_item_metas` WHERE `item_id` = 2');
$namelist = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT name FROM `wp__frm_fields` WHERE form_id = 2');
echo "<table>";
if ( !empty( $centr ) ) {
    foreach ($namelist as $key) {
            # code...
        echo "<tr><td>" . $key->name . "</tr></td>";
    }
    foreach ( $centr as $r ) {

        echo"<tr><td>" . $r->meta_value . "</tr></td>";

    }
}
echo "</table>";
```

I'd like the second echo to start in a new column, instead of displaying more rows in the same one.

Comment: That displays all the data in the last row. That won't work

Comment: are the two lists always guaranteed to be of identical length? Is there a meaningful relationship between the first record in $centr and the first record in $namelist that would justify showing them side-by-side? And the same for all the others? It feels like, looking at the table names, you perhaps should be solving this as one query with an INNER JOIN? Then the records come out next to each other in one result set. But I can't be sure without seeing the table structure and relationships.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is what you want

```
echo "<table>";
    if ( !empty( $centr ) ) {
       echo "<tr><td>";
             foreach ($namelist as $key) {
                echo "<table><tr><td>" . $key->name . "</td></tr></table>";
             }
        echo "</td><td>";
             foreach ( $centr as $r ) {
                    echo"<table><tr><td>" . $r->meta_value . "</td></tr></table>";
                }   
       echo "</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
```

Comment: this will repeat all of the $centr values on _every_ row. Not sure that's what's wanted. Question talks about two columns, but this will create `sizeof($centr)` extra columns

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work. As ADyson said, it repeats all of the $centr values on every row of $namelist.

Comment: ok.. what you actually want?, can you print the desired result

Comment: The two have identical length. the name list contains the name of the fields and the centr contains the values inserted in said field. So basically what I want is to display a table where first column contains the list of the names of the fields and the second column its respective values. e.g.
column 1: https://gyazo.com/764c074f307331346603465f585ba9c7
column 2: https://gyazo.com/50163667b078ecb5ffa51f45c216d60e

Comment: @R1ddler almost certainly they have a relationship within the DB structure. It'll be a trivial problem to solve in PHP if you can write a single SQL query which pulls them out in one result set containing the two related columns. You just need to find the field which joins the two tables (e.g. a shared ID, possibly the route will be through another table if it's many-to-many) and use INNER JOIN on that field. you can see the foreign keys defined on the table(s) to trace how they're related. If they aren't related it's hard to see how the application itself can relate the answers to the fields.

Comment: check the updated code @R1ddler i cant see your image posted

Comment: That gave the desired result